# How can additional nodelets be attached to the stereo_image_proc's nodelet manager in Diamondback?

Tags: ros, nodelet, image-proc, stereo, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to add in image processing attached to the `points2` and `disparity` output of `stereo_image_proc`, but can't figure out how to either get the `stereo_image_proc` stack nodelets to attach to my nodelet manager or attach to theirs.

Attempting to load nodelets using `stereo_image_proc` fails.

And the configuration done inside of `stereo_image_proc` is complex and done programmatically as work around to a topic remapping problem, and so I was unable to rebuild `stereo_image_proc`'s elements:

- `image_proc/rect`
- `stereo_image/disparity`
- `stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2`

... into the same functionality using simply a launch file which had a nodelet manager I could attach to.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9906/how-can-additional-nodelets-be-attached-to-the-stereo_image_proc%27s-nodelet-manager-in-diamondback?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the `stereo_image_proc`'s nodelet manager is created with the nodelet manager API turned off which prevents other nodelets from being attached to it.

My work around was to copy stereo_image_proc.cpp to my own package, and modifying the constructor call to enable the nodelet manager API:

```
nodelet::Loader manager(true); // was false
```

It's then possible to attach additional nodelets to this modified `stereo_image_proc` though be careful not to try to name the resulting node executable as `stereo_image_proc` as this will collide since `stereo_image_proc` will need to be a dependency of your package.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-05**:
Yeah, I'd file a ticket, but I've heard that it won't be done programmatically in the next release so it won't matter any more. Not sure why anyone ever sets that to false; perceived cleanliness I suppose.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-05-05**:
Deja vu.. http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110404.053527.ef774040.en.html